# How to retrieve status of a livestream from an xml file

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am in the process of making a website on Dreamweaver CC. On one of the pages, I want there to be a section where the page tells you a streamer's name (from livestream) and right next to it, their status of whether they are live or not.

Livestream's api provides a link that retrieves the status in the form of an .xml file. ex. [xkainlessx.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/livestatus.xml](http://xkainlessx.api.channel.livestream.com/2.0/livestatus.xml). The name of the streamer is in this format: x[channel name]x.api....

if the isLive status is false, I want some image in the html to stay as default (probably just a red dot). If the isLive status is true, I want the image in the html to change to a green dot or something.

I don't know how to use the script tags in html and I don't know javascript anyway so I have been spending a long time trying to solve this problem.

I have searched multiple sites for a solution from stackoverflow all the way to posting in the [livestream.com forums](http://www.livestream.com/forum/showthread.php?p=42474#post42474).

If anyone can simplify this for me, that would be great!

Comment: Can you use other libraries? If so I recommend jquery (especially for doing the http api request). If not, you may have to deal with the http request object quirks between multiple browswers. There are a lot of questions on here (stackoverflow) already that detail how to parse xml with javascript (and jquery).

Comment: I would be willing to use jquery but i understand it even less. I have tried but I don't know how to correlate the elements I need in my xml file to the elements in the examples.